# How can I design a query to display content from other Users I "follwow" in Parse (Android)?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

I was thinking each User in my app could have a "following" column (Array) which stores the objectIds of other Users whose content they want to see. Would the following work?

```
List<String> meFollowing = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("following");

ParseQuery<ParseObject> yeetQuery = new ParseQuery<>(ParseConstants.CLASS_POST);
        query.whereContainedIn("authorObjectId", meFollowing);
        query.orderByDescending(ParseConstants.KEY_LAST_REPLY_UPDATED_AT);
        query.include("author");
        query.include("pollObject");
```

Is there anything potentially seriously inefficient about this? Say, when the Array of other Users I'm following gets too large? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To manage High number of followers/followings I recommend you to use ParseRelation instead of Array. (cf[http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#many-to-many]).
For example :

```
ParseRelation<ParseUser> relation = getCurrentUser().getRelation("following");
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = relation.getQuery();
```